Delete OCI Compartments
I'm trying to delete unwanted OCI compartments, but can't seem to do it. When I look in Tenancy Explorer, the compartments are empty.
The only thing I can find is: Log Groups in compartment shows _Audit, but I can't delete that.
I just want to delete everything and every compartment. I want to keep nothing.

I see I can rename them. That is something.
